# Cannot assign a ref to a component in a render prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose you have a simple react application (see my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9jz39qmw5p)):

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class RenderPropComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.example.test());
    return this.props.render();
  }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  test = () => console.log('Test successful!');

  render() {
    return <h1>I am an example!</h1>;
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <RenderPropComponent
    render={() => {
      return (
        <Example ref={node => this.example = node} />
      )
    }}
  />
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This causes the error:

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
```

How can I assign a `ref` to a component rendered via render prop?

I know I can accomplish this with `this.props.children` as follows:

```
class RenderPropComponent extends React.Component {
  const childComponents = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
      return React.cloneElement(child, {ref: node => this.example = node})
  });
  console.log(this.example.test());
  render() {  
    return <div>{childComponents}</div>;
  }
}

...

<RenderPropComponent>
    <Example />
</RenderPropComponent>
```

But I would like to be able to use a render prop to do this! Any suggestions?

Comment: `this` inside your render prop is undefined because it's in functional component and not a class. Even if it was in a class, `this` would belong to `App` and not your component

Comment: Moreover, if you think about it, even if that wasn't the case, there's no way you could access the ref inside the render prop component because the stuff that goes into the render prop hasn't been rendered

Comment: Why do you want to pass down the entire render function? It is definitely an anti-pattern which breaks encapsulation and can lead to issues like this one. If you want some content from parent element to show up in children, you can nest tags and use `props.children` in the child component to modify and display nested content.

Comment: @NikitaIsaev, I think calling it an anti-patter is a bit over the top. A lot of people in the react-land use render props. I.e. https://cdb.reacttraining.com/use-a-render-prop-50de598f11ce

Comment: @GlebKost, this makes components too specific and mixes up responsibility, and I can’t imagine any use case where it could be necessary. Soon people will start passing down setState, componentWillMount etc, all the code will be in the root component, and there will be a single reusable component like `<IAmDesignedToDoWhateverJustGiveMeProps>

Comment: @KitIsaev the render prop pattern facilitates making components more reusable and decoupled, providing a mixin-like ability similar to higher order components. Rather than an HOC, a component can simply accept a prop that is a function (a "render prop"), and render the output of calling that function, passing to it any data contained in the parent component. This exposes an 'api' into the parent that can be passed back to any child as props. It's still useful practice but in most cases now using the Hooks api for reusable state/behavior unrelated to rendering is a better practice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not fully sure if it fits your case, but maybe you can pass the setRef function as an argument to the render prop? Like in this forked [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zqzkzv2vy4).

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setRef = this.setRef.bind(this);
  }
  setRef(node) {
    this.example = node; 
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.example && this.example.test());
    return this.props.render(this.setRef);
  }
}

class Example extends React.Component {
  test = () => console.log('Test successful!');

  render() {
    return <h1>I am an example!</h1>;
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello 
      name="CodeSandbox" 
      render={(setRef) => {
        return (
          <Example ref={setRef} />
        )
      }}
    />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The only problem i see here, is that on initial render this.example will not be available (that's why I've added a guard to the console log) and after it will be set, the rerender will not be triggered (since it's set on the instance and not in the state). If a rerender is needed, we can store the ref in the component state or force the rerender.

On the other hand, if you need a ref to be used in some event handler later on, that should do the trick without rerendering.

Comment: I like this approach. Thank you

Comment: @andrewhl, glad to hear! If it works for you, I'd greatly appreciate if you mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

Look carefully, `this` keyword is used in the global scope, not in the scope of the `example` component.

```
const App = () => (
  <RenderPropComponent
    render={() => {
      return (
        <Example ref={node => this.example = node} />
      )
    }}
  />
);
```

If you didn’t spot it yet, take a look at that snippet:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(stuffToDo) {
    this.bar = ‘bar’;
    this.stuffToDo = stuffToDo
  }
  doStuff() {
    this.stuffToDo();
  }
}

new Foo(() => console.log(this.bar)).doStuff();
```

This will log `undefined`, not `bar`, because `this` is derived from the current closure.

Comment: I'm aware that this is the reason why my ref is not available in the calling component context. My question is how can I get around this? You didn't actually answer my question, but rather seem to be trying to show that the question itself is invalid, which I believe is misguided and unhelpful.